# How can I trace an apparent memory leak in an asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, iis, memory-leaks

Some background info:

- We have several websites running on a 64-bit machine with IIS6
- These websites all have the same core code, but different skins and content
- We have a SQL 2005 database which is fairly heavily used throughout the site
- Historically we've used SQL stored procs, but have been gradually transitioning to NHibernate. The majority of our code uses NHibernate now, but not all.
- These sites have been running fine on our live web server for a while, although we get a few errors a day regarding SQL connectivity / deadlocking.

Last Thursday we noticed the sites going very slow, then checking task manager revealed one of the websites was hogging over 1.6Gb of memory. Ever since then we've been restarting the app and watching it slowly increase in size over the course of the day.

We apparently have a memory leak (or at least, that's the effect), but I'm losing hair trying to work out how to trace it.

It only appears to be happening on this one website, even though as far as I am aware nothing had changed in the code before it started happenning. It is, however, our busiest website so it could be a traffic issue.

Debug Diagnostics hasn't revealed any issues.

Refreshing certain pages very quickly causes the memory to jump up rapidly, then fall slightly, but all the time the gradual progression is upwards.

I cannot replicate the issue on our test servers or locally. Probably because the traffic has something to do with it.

My suspicion is that the problem lies in database connectivity / locking. However, I'm not sure how that would cause the problem specified.

Any ideas?

*Edit*

Okay so not exactly sure I've found the problem but we're getting closer. It's definately SQL related. The error log reveals lots of errors since last thursday.

It all happened after we ran some windows updates on our servers. One of the updates failed on the SQL server so not sure if this caused some problems.

The warnings we're getting are:

- SQL Server has encountered XX occurence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file .. tempdb.mdf

Where XX is anything between 17 and 90! Does that sound like a deadlocking issue?

Followed by the following erors:

- Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection

These coincide with our log times for when the websites have been "blipping".

We've increased the page file size on SQL server to the recommended size, as it was set to a max of 4Gb, but recommended was 12Gb. I think we may need to roll back the windows updates we did on Thursday if that doesn't fix it.

Unfortunately I can't get into Activity monitor as it tells me Timeout expired!

**Edit**

Okay after a reboot I'm into Activity monitor. How many sleeping processes would you say would be normal? We have roughly 127 sleeping. That's serving over 10 websites.

If there is a deadlock or timeout issue, will NHibernate not clean up its connections properly?

Comment: check your sql-server activitymonitor, maybe your app isn`t leaking memory but sql-server connections. if this is the case you should see alot sleeping processes.

Comment: How far did you get with DebugDiag?

Comment: Hi Kev - not very far. It didn't report any problems at all. I don't think it was an IIS problem after all, but as marc.d suggested, sql-server connections being held up due to SQL problems.

Comment: @Hainesy your edit reads like you did some server maintance, did this include the update or installation of anti-virus software? if yes you should try to disable the real-time protection or at least exclude mdf, ldf and ndf files.

Comment: @marc.d actually all I did was install windows updates. Some of them failed. But we do have anti-virus installed anyway, I will follow your advice and disable those file types.

Comment: Can you access the server from your version of query analyzer or enterprise manager without any problems? If you can it could be a permissions issue from the websites. Have you tried manually patching sql server with the latest update? Id it with all of the sites or specific ones?

Comment: @Varuuknahl - Yes I regularly interact with the server with enterprise manager with no problems. We tried patching to 2005 SP3 today but the update failed 3 times in a row, so we gave up. I'm not quite sure which part your describing as a permissions issue?

Comment: If it is not running slow from your enterprise environment then you are only having the issue from web related queries. When I have run into this problem in the past it was always a permissions and timeout issue related to only my web generated queries, which meant my installation was fine, although it sounds like there is an issue with yours. I was able to solve my problem by setting my timeout period longer and then systematically running through my scripts and functions until I found the one that was not setup correctly. Either that or some college kid was trying to access my database.

Comment: @Varuuknahl - I'm pretty sure the issue centres around the fact that a large number of queries on our website centre around a single table in SQL... which is basically causing locking & timeouts.

Comment: That could do it. If that is the case all you can do is refine your procs to be more restrictive. Query analyzer has a nice tool to see whare your heaviest query subsets are, Execution Plan. I am assuming you cannot shrink the table size by archiving records. You could also try working from Views for your more common searches/tasks on that table. Short of taking a look at your procs or your database I don't think I can offer anything else. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so in the end it seems it's quite complex. Sql deadlocks and data problems, heightened it seems by anti-virus software that was locking up or choking on a file.

Turning off the anti-virus reduced the problems, but we still need to resolve the underlying data issues.